# Visual Studio Code not opening any python interpret

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with opening and running python on VS Code. In particular, I cannot open any python interpret regardless of having python installed on the computer and the python extension in VS code.

1 week ago, there was no issue with that, I opened VS Code, followed the instructions and python was running (however without any packages or libraries). Because I use python for Data Science projects, I decided to integrate Jupyter notebook - here again, no issues.
Afterwards, I got the idea that I should be able to import libraries and run codes in file_name.py, not only file_other_name.ipynb, so I was trying to create an environment in my project folder that will store installed packages by typing `py -3 -m venv .venv .venv\scripts\activate` and `python -m pip install matplotlib` in the terminal. Unfortunately, that did not work when running a basic script - getting a message "Activate.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system."

Hence, I set up the powershell to `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`. Once, I restarted VS Code, the current environment started showing a message 'Select Python Interpret'. I tried to reinstall the python extension and select from the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) any of the python interprets, that it is giving me but nothing happens. The message does not change regardless of how many times I have specified which interpret to open. Any idea how I can open the python interpret once again?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgaRV.png)

Comment: Do you mean even python interpreters are listed, you're not able to select and set it to the current project?

Comment: yes, you can see in the provided screenshot that various python interpreters are listed but when either is clicked/entered, nothing happens

Comment: Try to reinstall **Python** extension and about creating virtual environment, please refer to [Select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: Update: I have deleted the environment above and created the environment again. Now the interpret is showing and I even ran the code (line by line), however still 2 warnings are left from the line about 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' and 'import numpy as np'. When I closed VS code and opened it again, nothing worked. I cannot understand why I need to built everytime somekind of environment for parts of the code to run. Cannot it read it globally like every other software? In Jupiter or RStudio, a simple installing of the package if you don't have it (just once) and import is all they need.

Comment: Once you've installed the module in a environment, then every time you open the same environment, it will be there and like you say, import is all need. Are you sure you installed it successfully and open with the same environment?

Comment: Update2: Ok, I have the virtual environment in my folder. The workspace is also interpreting Python from that virtual environment - great. I installed the matplotlib - okay. Then when running line by line the code it worked, but when running the whole script it didn't. Restarted the program, the interpret is selected etc. but now even running line by line the code does not work. When I try to install again matplotlib it states that "Requirement already satisfied:" but still it does not allow the import function to work.

Comment: Here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/tLP6dV2 
As you said, the venv is loading and the interpret is working but still cannot run the code.

Comment: No, you didn't use the selected .venv as your environment in Terminal, Ctrl+Shift+` will open a new integrated Terminal, at the same time if you don't change the default settings, the environment would be activated, so the prefix in your terminal should be `(.venv) PS D:\myProjects\VSCode\Python\A>`, but the screenshot you post didn't like this, which means you still use the global environment not the selected virtual environment, so the project can't find the module in .venv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a default setting called `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,` so every time you create an virtual environment and select it as your interpreter, don't forget to open a new integrated Terminal(**Ctrl+Shift+`**) to activate it.

**[EDIT]**

When you open a new integrated Terminal, there'll be an statement executed **automatically**: that's a file in your created .`venv`, which is by red underlined in the following screenshot. Then you get a virtual name prefix before PS, that means you've activated it successfully.

If the `Activate.ps1` isn't executed automatically, turn to the .venv folder, copy its absolute path then run it in Terminal still can activate the environment.

Then go on development, like installing the required module:
[image]

Comment: Ok, I opened a new integrated terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`) and added 'conda activate venv', then I think it propt me to install the Powershell extension, so I did. Now back to the code it works when I run line by line the code (even after restarting VS code - hurray!), but still when I try to run python file in terminal (the play button or right-click -> run python file in terminal, it does not work. https://ibb.co/CvMyWsK 
I went to the Microsoft link but it is the same - describing how to Unrestrict your Execution Policy

Comment: Sorry for my inappropriate reproduction to questions. I've create a same .venv and update my answer, please have a check.

Comment: Perfect, that works now! My Activate.ps1 was executing automatically but throwing an Error, which was fixed after opening PowerShell as admin and running ```Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser``` and confirming all. Afterwards, I restarted VSCode and now when the workspace with the .```venv``` is prompt to open it executes the ```Activate.ps1``` automatically and without warnings or errors (similar to your screenshot).

Comment: @AndreyShumilov.  That's great! Happy coding :-)